# How to get a repository or the current TypeORM instance of a NestFastifyApplication object?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am building an API with nest. For E2E tests I am using Jest, in the beforeAll() I instantiate a complete NestJS application using createNestApplication from the AppModule:

```
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication<NestFastifyApplication>(
      new FastifyAdapter(),
    );
    await app.init();
```

Tests and validations are carried out with the app object. For some validations, and to delete records from the database after testing, I am looking for a way to get from the app object the repositories of my entities, or at least, the instance of TypeOrm that has the connection to the database.

[Reviewing the object and its documentation](https://nestjs-doc.exceptionfound.com/interfaces/inestapplication.html) I found that nestJS provides some methods to extract modules, or providers from this object, but I haven't seen anything to extract the DB connection instance. I tried to extract the TypeOrm module using the [select method](https://nestjs-doc.exceptionfound.com/interfaces/inestapplication.html#select) like this:

```
    const typeOrmModule = app.select(TypeOrmModule);
```

But that causes the error:
Nest could not select the given module (it does not exist in current context)

I don't want to have to generate a new connection to the DB knowing that the app object already has one. So I wonder if there is a way to extract that instance of the connection or the repositories that the object has inside. Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't `app.get(getConnectionToken(), { strict: false })` work?

Comment: Man, it wasn't exactly like that, but your comment guided me to find the solution. The method getConnectionToken() is deprecated, so, I look for another method from @nestjs/typeorm and I found getRepositoryToken(Entity). It returns the token for the entitie's repo and with it I could get the repo I needed. I'll answer the question with this solution. Thank you :)

Comment: Ah, you're right. TypeORM v0.3 and all that. The other option is `getDataSourceToken()` instead of getting a repo directly

Answer (score 5):

Jay McDoniel's comment guided me to find the solution. The method `getRepositoryToken(Entity)` from `@nestjs/typeorm` returns the token for the entitie's repo and with it I could get the repo I needed:

```
    const repo = app.get<Repository<Entity>>(getRepositoryToken(Entity));
```